# I am trying to find the size of data sent after compression in libwebsockets from client. How can i achieve it?

Tags: c, libwebsockets

How can I determine the size of data being sent after compression in libwebsocket. I tried getting stats about size of data after compression from libwebsocket metrics but did not find one. How can I achieve this from libwebsocket?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.